# Transfer from one profile to another - Rails and Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I write for the first time and I would be glad if someone help me.

I create a rails app with stripe payment and have two type of customers.

When customer1 logs into the system, he needs to fill payment credentials form(cardholder, CVC, cart number). With form information and stripe.js is generated card_token I use the token to create customer and save to database.

When customer2 logs into the system, I use stripe connect  to connect my system with customer2 stripe account.

How can I transfer money from customer1 to customer2`s account.I use

```
Stripe.api_key = PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY
Stripe::Charge.create({
  :amount => 1000,
  :currency => "usd",
  :source => {TOKEN},
  :destination => {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}
})
```

and try with this curl request:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges \
   -u {PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}: \
   -d customer={STRIPE_CUSTOMER_ID} \
   -d amount=1000 \
   -d currency=usd \
   -d destination={CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID} \
   -d application_fee=200
```

but both give me an error:

```
"type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Invalid API Key provided: {**_****_********************xUW}"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!